# Viewing a TIFF stream using the .NET webbrowser control in C# doesn't show image

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, tiff

I have a windows form that is using a Webbrowser control to view documents on a web server. 
When it tries to display a TIFF, it just displays a blank screen. It works with other file types just fine.

The URL to the TIFF works fine if I paste it into Firefox.

Will this flat out not work, am I doing something wrong? Should I invest in an imaging library for rendering TIFFs myself?

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Eli.

Comment: Don't test it with FireFox, use Internet Explorer.  That's what WB uses.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for [Atalasoft](http://www.atalasoft.com).
TIFF isn't a typically well-supported format in web browsers.  We have components that include an AJAX image viewer that can handle many image formats not supported by typical browsers.  You can try out our demo [here](http://www.atalasoft.com/ajaxannotations8.0a/).  We include controls for thumbnail views, annotations and server side image processing.